# Object properties must be on a new line with ESLint

Tags: javascript, eslint

let's say I have the following variable:

`const myObject = { property1: 'value1', property2: 'value2', property3: 'value3' };`

I want to enforce an eslint rule so that if an object has a minimum of three properties, then each property must go on a new line, such as below:

```
const myObject = {
  property1: 'value1',
  property2: 'value2',
  property3: 'value3',
};
```

However, if I use the eslint rule `object-curly-newline`, it appears that the following is acceptable, and this is what get's automatically formatted when `eslint --fix` runs:

```
const myObject = {
  property1: 'value1', property2: 'value2', property3: 'value3',
};
```

How can I enforce an eslint rule that makes sure that each new property is on a new line? Thanks!

Comment: There is an [`object-property-newline`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/object-property-newline) rule but it might not suit your use-case, particularly when using it with `--fix`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
"object-curly-newline": ["error", { "multiline": true }],
"object-curly-spacing": ["error", "always"]
```

Answer (score 1):

**To Enforce an Eslint rule for an object with a minimum number of properties where each property must go on a new line, you need to use the `object-curly-newline` along with the `multiline` and `minProperties` options.**

Here is an example configuration in which ESLint will enforce that objects with at least three properties have each property on a new line.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "object-curly-newline": ["error", {
      "ObjectExpression": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 3 },
    }]
  }
}
```

### Could be useful too-

The above rule is not limited to **object literals** only. There are a few more [options](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/object-curly-newline#options) also mentioned in the documentation where this rule can be enforced for **destructuring assignments**, and **import and export properties** as well.

Here is the complete configuration example in which ESLint will enforce the `object-curly-newline` rule for:

- Object literals with at least three properties
- Destructuring assignments that involve objects
- Import statements with at least three imported properties
- Export statements with at least three exported properties

```
{
  "rules": {
    "object-curly-newline": ["error", {
      "ObjectExpression": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 3 },
      "ObjectPattern": { "multiline": true },
      "ImportDeclaration": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 3 },
      "ExportDeclaration": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 3 }
    }]
  }
}
```

### An example

As per the above-written rule, if you have an example code like this-

```
const obj = { p1: 'v1', p2: 'v2', p3: 'v3' };
const { k1, k2, k3 } = obj;
import { i1, i2, i3 } from './somePath';
export { e1, e2, e3 };
```

ESLint should enforce the above written `object-curly-newline` rule for each of these cases and suggest the following fix-

```
const obj = {
  p1: 'v1',
  p2: 'v2',
  p3: 'v3',
};
const {
  k1,
  k2,
  k3,
} = obj;
import {
  i1,
  i2,
  i3,
} from './somePath';
export {
  e1,
  e2,
  e3,
};
```

You can read more about each option in detail [here](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/object-curly-newline#rule-details).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/object-curly-newline#multiline mixed with https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/object-curly-newline#minproperties

In your case you need

```
object-curly-newline: ["error", { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 3 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **object-curly-newline** by setting option **multiline** to **true**.

For Example in **.eslintrc**, it would be written as :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "object-curly-newline": ["error", {
      "multiline": true,
      "consistent": true
    }]
  }
}
```

**Examples:**

The above code will throw an **error** in this type of code line :

```
const dummyObject = { p1: 'v1', p2: 'v2', p3: 'v3' };
```

The above code will work correctly when above **dummyObject** is written as:

```
const dummyObject = {
  p1: 'v1',
  p2: 'v2',
  p3: 'v3',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `prettier` for this purpose instead of using the option available by `eslint` in my projects.

That being said, this will not work out of the box and conflict with eslint. You must add the following to your rules in the `.eslintrc.js` file:

`'object-curly-newline': 0,`

Refer this section here in the article - I think it will help you achieve your result.

If you have a multiline object that you’d like to join up into a single line:

```
const user = {
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 30,
};

// All you need to do is remove the newline after {:

const user = {  name: "John Doe",
  age: 30
};

// then run Prettier:

const user = { name: "John Doe", age: 30 };

// If you’d like to go multiline again, add in a newline after {:

const user = {
 name: "John Doe", age: 30 };

// run Prettier:

const user = {
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 30,
};
```

The rationale is that I do not need to do much tinkering as that needed in the `eslint` option.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#multi-line-objects